# Android In App Billing: Purchase Validation When Multiple Accounts Present In Google Play

Tags: android, validation, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I validate In-App Purchase upon app startup. The problem I am facing is when some users have multiple accounts in Google Play:

- User makes a purchase with Account A
- Time passes, and user logs in with Account B in GooglePlay
- User re-opens the app after some time, purchase is no longer recognized as logged in with Account B
- Logging back into Account A in Google Play solves the problem

I would like to successfully validate the purchase as long as 1 of the accounts on the device was used to made the purchase regardless of the account currently logged in in GooglePlay.

Is there a way to achieve this, to validate across all accounts on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Change the criteria of validation. use the email-id and phones imei to validate, this is one of the way. or you can access accounts and check if the email-id is there or not to validate. hope you understood. its upto ur requirement. if the app is mobile based used imei. if it is plateform based i mean if it runs also in browser use email id

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is a bit abstract. I am using Google's IabHelper classes and the only param I can specify is the SKU list. Do you have a code sample to share?

Comment: if you are using those classes then you cannot do that validation. google doesnot support sharing of purchases

Comment: Could you please suggest a more concrete answer with a corresponding code sample? Thanks.

Comment: It is not supported. you cannot validate the transaction when someone is not logged on with the account he used to purchase the item. he will have to login with the same id to receive the item

Comment: Thanks, to clarify both accounts are added and technically logged in. But only one selected at a time in Google Play.

Comment: @AlexVPerl What will you do if user singed in with more than 1 Google Account?

Comment: @Sunshinetpu In my experience, that does not cause a problem. User just must be signed in from the account used to make the purchase.